# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass. The views and the controller match up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have looked all over on stack overflow to try to fix this problem and I can't seem to find a fix. I can include more code if needed.

I tried changing in the controller to comment to comments and that does not change anything.

I tried changing to comments to comment and that does not change anything.

I am legit stuck on this and I want to know why this is happening. Thanks

Comments_controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
    @comments = @pin.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:pin_id, :body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

My index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing comments</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= comment.link_id %></td>
        <td><%= comment.body %></td>
        <td><%= comment.user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', comment %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %>
```

Comment: i think index method in controller is missing?

Comment: Thank you. I cant believe I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an index method to the controller:

```
def index
  @comments = Comment.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @comments }
  end
end
```